# Unable to make background image full screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a website using parallax.

I am having troubles with CSS. Below is the HTML:

```
<div id="skrollr-body">

        <div class="subnav"> 
            <ul  id="nav">
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#foo">Foo</a></li>

            </ul> 
        </div>


            <div id="home" class="centered" data-0="height:100%;" data-1000="height:0%;" > 
                <div class="zebra">
                     <div class="contentWrap">

                          test

                     </div>         
                </div> 
            </div>


            <div id="foo" class="centered" data-1000="height:100%;" data-2000="height:0%;">
                <div class="world">
                         <div class="contentWrap">

                              test

                         </div>         
                 </div> 

            </div> 
</div>
```

and here is the css:

```
#home {  
    background: #dedede;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 901;
} 
#foo{background: yellow; z-index:800;}  

.zebra {
    background-image: url("/img/zebra-pattern.png");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.world {
    background-image: url("/img/world.jpg");
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.contentWrap{ 
    position: absolute; 
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

My problem is if i dont put height explicitly, background image is not becoming full screen.

any advice?

Comment: A JsFiddle would help me work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a percentage height to work on any element, it's parent must have some kind of height set on it. That parent's height can be a percentage too, but, in that case, for that percentage to work, it's own parent  must also have some kind of height set on it. And this goes all the way up to the html element.

In your case, if `#skrollr-body` is a/the direct child of the `body` element, you must include this in your stylesheet:

```
html,
body, 
#skrollr-body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I already have that : `#skrollr-body {width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed; }
#skrollr-body  div { width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; position:absolute; }`

Comment: On the `body` and `html` elements too?

Comment: I would have to see a fiddle I guess.

Comment: But have you figured it out? I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem using "background:cover" and skrollr.

The problem stems from the fact that "cover" designates the size of the image (to cover the element) and skrollr uses "background-position" to offset the image... if the image is only as big as the element that contains it, when it 'skrolls' it will leave blank space.  I'm writing a bit of jquery to resize my background to be the equivalent of "cover + 10%".

If anyone finishes this before I do, I'd love to see it!

**~~ A much easier option is to make sure that your image is much taller than it is wide. (if you are vertically animating it with skrollr)**